# Excel Spreadsheet data movement

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have copied data from a main list on one tab on to another list on the next tab of the same sheet.  I have done this by copying each cell across individually.  Now, when I sort the original sheet (for example by a-z) the data on the second sheet now corresponds to the sorted and not the original list.

I want the second tab to only display the details I originally copied before sorting.

Comment: What kind of data is on the main list? You said you copied them individually, but they seemed to be linked somehow. Is it pivot chart data?

Comment: You have to create a copy of sheet not each cell individually in that case you will sort one tab and the copy will remain the same

Answer (score 2):

check the data you have pasted, you could have pasted as a link to the original data, copy the data again and right click where you want to paste and select paste as values.